# IntelliJ throws exception from simple strings after update

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Afther the update on IntelliJ Community Edition. It gives me Exception on simple strings like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class asdasd {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String random = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(random);
    }
 }

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:     "gosho"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
at P01_PersonalTitles.main(P01_PersonalTitles.java:7)
```

I'm new to coding, what do i do?
Even code that used to work before with no problem, now gives the same exception.

Comment: You're trying to start a `main` from `P01_PersonalTitles` instead of `asdasd`, as the exception says. Check your run configurations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code you posted is not consistent with the Exception. Based only in the exception, you're trying to convert the String "gosho" to a Number (which is incorrect).

So, you should:

1. Change the code for converting that string
2. Change the input text, or
3. Enclose your code in a block try/catch, in order to handle this
   errors (could be a NumberFormatException)

The robust and recomended solution is the 3.

Comment: Oh, you were right. It was running a code from another class. Definitely my mistake. Sorry for the inconvenience.